# Save binary information to a file

Tags: ios, swift, stream, file-writing

I receive binary information via stream in Swift. Lets say the information is a picture. I now want to save the picture. How is this possible?

I tried following:

```
let bufferSize = 154000
var buffer = [UInt8](count: bufferSize, repeatedValue: 0)
var bytesRead = inputStream?.read(&buffer, maxLength: bufferSize)
if bytesRead > 0 {

var bytesWrittenSoFar = 0
do {
    var diffbytes = bytesRead! - bytesWrittenSoFar

    fileStream?.open()
    fileStream?.write(UnsafePointer(&buffer[bytesWrittenSoFar]), maxLength: diffbytes)

} while (bytesWrittenSoFar != bytesRead);
```

But when I try to write (fileStream?.write...) I get following error: "Could not find an overload for 'init' that accepts the supplied arguments

Thank you for your answer in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the initialization of UnsafePointer.  In this case, you don't need it at all, you can just pass `&buffer[bytesWrittenSoFar]`, as that is an acceptable value to pass to a function that needs an unsafePointer, per the discussion in the apple book "Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C".